# Flush cache in case of WSOD without Drush on shared host

Tags: 8, drush

I have installed Drupal from using build-in scripts on [runcloud.io](https://runcloud.io/), but I have noticed that Drush is not available. They have replied:

> Sorry, it is not possible to install drush into Runcloud. Because the
>   installation leads to php crash as it will erase cerain php modules

I get used to using Drush, especially when Drupal 8 website encountered an unexpected error, without this option I don't see the way how to clear the cache without UI, restore from backup etc.

Are there any other options to rebuild caches without Drush to recover the website from an unexpected error?

Comment: Recover the website? Or clear cache? Well, and you should definitely look for another hoster. "The installation of Drush leads to PHP crash as it will erase certain PHP modules"... WTF?

Comment: ... sometimes recover from backup. I'm also surprised why I can't install drush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get used to using Drush, especially when Drupal 8 website
>   encountered an unexpected error, without this option I don't see the
>   way how to clear the cache without UI.

Run `www.mysite.com/update.php`. This clears the cache, even when no updates are to run.

If you don't have access set `$settings['update_free_access'] = TRUE;` temporarily in settings.php.